# How to change the active printer in MS word using delphi xe3

Tags: delphi, printing, ms-word

i open a MS Word document using the following code:

```
  try
  { Open the document}
   WrdApp := CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');
   wrdDoc := 'temp.docx');
  // Wrddoc.SaveAs('temp2.docx');
  except
   on E: Exception do
    begin
     E.Message := 'Could Not Execute MS WORD!';
     raise;
    end;
  end;
```

And print it using `wrdapp.Printout`

I have a combobox that has a list of printer names from the computer using the code:

```
Combobox32.Items.Assign(Printer.Printers);
```

How do i change the active printer in MS Word to the selected printer in the combobox, so that when i call `wrdapp.Printout` it will print from the printer selected in the combobox?

thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: See [Application.ActivePrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff821995%28v=office.14%29.aspx), *but* see the remark there (that it actually changes the system default printer).

Comment: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/9/939248.html and/or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply assing WrdApp.ActivePrinter with the name of the printer you want to use. In your case, you picjk it from the item selected in the combobox.
For a code example, see this: http://francois-piette.blogspot.be/2014/02/automate-word-document-print-using.html

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. i did try similar code before, but kept getting an error.

i don't know why this worked while the other did not, but thanks